# Mean.io + prerender

Tags: angularjs, prerender, mean-stack, mean.io

I'm using Mean Stack and trying to use Prerender for SEO.
So i followed the instructions and installed the prerender package and added this to the index.js:

```
// Start the app by listening on <port>
var port = process.env.PORT || config.port;

var prerender =
    require('prerender-node').set('prerenderServiceUrl', 'http://samura.pt:2999');
app.use(prerender);

app.listen(port);
console.log('Express app started on port ' + port);

// Initializing logger
logger.init(app, passport, mongoose);
```

Now everytime i try any cached page like `http://idealmovel.pt/?_escaped_fragment_=` it still delivers the normal page, as you can see by deactivating the javascript on your browser.
The prerender is installed otherwise it would show errors.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to move the prerender code from below the port definition to before the line:

```
require('./config/express')(app, passport, db);
```

Something happens in the middle that makes the prerender not to trigger.